# Commit e Rolback Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, commit

Galera, estou usando a classe Mysqli do PHP e me deparei na seguinte situação...

Eu tenho duas tabelas, a tabela A é a principal e a tabela B é a filha até ai está ok, o que preciso fazer é o tratamento do commit e rollback para evitar falhas futuramente desta maneira montei o seguinte Script...

```
$DB->mConnect();
$DB->Mysqli->autocommit(false);

$er = true;

$query = "insert into (descricao) values ('testes')";
$er = !$DB->Mysqli->query($query) ? false : true;
$codigo = $DB->Mysqli->insert_id;

$query2 = "insert into (cod_pai, descricao) values (".$codigo.", 'teste filho')";
$er = !$DB->Mysqli->query($query2) ? false : true;

$er ? $DB->Mysqli->commit() : $DB->Mysqli->rollback();

var_dump($err);
```

Agora vem a minha dúvida, a tabela filha B é dependente do codigo auto incremente que é gerado na tabela A, o que está ocorrendo é que da forma que fiz não está sendo gerado o Código, e desta maneira quando vai usar na tabela B fala que o código da tabela A nao existe.

Gostaria de saber o que fiz de errado?

Agradeço ajuda!

Comment: Inserindo manualmente no banco de dados, o `AUTO_INCREMENT` funciona? Verifica se a coluna `cod_pai` e as outras com A.I. são do tipo **INT** no BD. Muda a variável dentro do `vardump`, *err* não existe. Por convenção, utilize as cláusulas SQL sempre em maiúscula (SELECT, INSERT, etc).

Comment: O código carrega até o fim? Verificou se os dados são gravados no DB (exceto o id)?